# Can a Paladin and Cleric get married?

Tags: dnd-5e, roleplaying

I roleplay a Paladin of Bahamut and there's a Cleric of Selune in my party as well who over time my Paladin has become attracted to. The idea of marriage certainly exists as I've met husbands and wives in my travels; however, I've never met a married adventure. I can't think of any reason an adventurer *couldn't* marry (other than the obvious: they live a dangerous life and travel which might put a prospective partner off), but:

- Can a Paladin and Cleric, of Bahamut and Selune respectively, marry?
- Is it common that either of these classes, or adventurers in general marry?
- We are of the same race, human, but if we weren't would there be restrictions there?
- We are also of different genders, but if we were the same would that also impose an issue?
- If it's possible, how would it be done?

Comment: I can't remember where but I beleive I saw a suggested bond which suggested one was married with kids.

Comment: Pathfinder, but related: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/ceremony

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**There are no in-game restrictions that prevent any of this: it depends on the DM.**

This certainly adds fun roleplaying possibilities to a game. As to if it is possible, there are not reasons to not do so.

- Bahamut is Lawful Good, and Selûne is Chaotic Good. While they are on opposite ends of the Good spectrum, they are both Good. There is no known animosity between the Moonmaiden and *Darastrix Ux*, so there is no reason to assume that an outright ban in place.
- Paladins tend to be Lawful Good, an alignment that takes marriage as an institute rather seriously. Selûne's clergy is either LG, CG or CN, of whom the latter two have a more free approach to sexuality but can still marry someone they care for. As for Clerics, it can go either way.
- No problems here. Bahamut is a dragon. Selûne is not. While it is rare for dragons to marry at all, if their feelings are sincere and mutual I do not expect Bahamut to object to such a marriage.
- Restrictions based on gender are all up to the DM and their setting.
- The biggest problem I see with the marriage is the choice of priest. One of Bahamut or one of Selûne? Or take the middle ground and ask a cleric of Sune instead?

Answer (score 15):

## Ask your DM

None of these things are specified by rules—they're entirely the province of your DM and group's creativity.

Talk to your DM and find out—or work out together—what the answers are. Nobody outside of your group knows your group's world, and can't answer questions about it with any authority.

Answer (score 5):

Most D&D clergy seem to have no vows of celibacy, and may or may not be committed to chastity either. I'm not sure about Selune or Bahamut, but from what I know there should be no particular exceptions there. Keep in mind that in D&D settings, the various deities are generally perfectly fine with acknowledging their fellows: there is little or no exclusivity, so it's not like, say, a Christian marrying a Muslim or something like that.

It's not real common for adventurers to be married, but it happens from time to time; some gaming groups are quite fond of playing married characters and some not so much.

Restrictions on interracial marriage presumably vary wildly between different faiths. Again, I doubt there's anything specific in Selune's or Bahamut's teachings, except possibly chromatic and metallic dragons interbreeding.

Restrictions on same-sex marriage depends almost entirely on the group's own out-of-game ideas on the matter.

The most interesting sub-question is your last, but unfortunately that's also by far the broadest: designing a suitable ceremony for each of the innumerable combinations of Faith X and Deity Y is not especially practical to do ahead of time, so you'll just have to come up with the right stuff yourself, presumably mixing elements from both in an artistic way.

Comment: Christians do marry Muslims in real life, and I think it's usually their families that give them problems more than their deities (:

Comment: @octern: Since the deity in question is generally admitted to be the same one, that's not terribly surprising. The theologies are still incompatible, though, and the objections seem to be on theological grounds at least as often as on cultural.